# how can i get docs with unique sender in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm implementing a chat system using mongodb. Currently have a chat collection which looks like the json.

When showing the conversation list to my user, I want to fetch the last text from each of the conversations. means for each sender-receiver pair, I want to fetch exactly one document. How can build the query for this?

using `node 12.16.1` and  `mongoose 5.8.9`

```
  {
     "_id":"6184bd15b3f9ad1e34e0e7ea"},
     "sender": "6184bd15b3f9ad1e34e0d7ea"},
     "reciever": "618d4cec8904317075520d36"},
     "text":"hello"
  },
 {
     "_id":"6184bd15b3f9ad1e34e0e7ea"},
     "sender": "618d4cec8904317075520d36"},
     "reciever": "6184bd15b3f9ad1e34e0d7ea"},
     "text":"hello"
  },
  {
     "_id":"6184bd15b3f9ad1e34e0e7ea"},
     "sender": "618d4cec8904317075520338"},
     "reciever": "6184bd15b3f9ad1e34e0d7ea"},
     "text":"hello"
  },
]
```

Comment: Please provide sample data as json

Comment: @mohammadNaimi please check i have updated the question